# Connecting Wiimote to Dolphin Emulator

Tags: bluetooth

I having tremendous amount of trouble connecting my Wiimote with the dolphin emulator on Mac. I am using the latest version of dolphin. I have both the Wiimote and the Wiimote plus. The Mac bluetooth easily detects both Wiimotes and connects with no issues. While Dolphin detects the Wiimote to some extent (it shows up in the controllers dropdown in settings), it does not connect. The lights on the Wiimote stay flashing, it never actually connects completely. Any ideas why this is? Is anyone else having such issues?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

have you changed the settings in dolphin to "real controller"?

Comment: Brief comments like this are better as a "comment" as you provide no other information. EG avoid short one-line answers.